# How to use Page Object pattern with Cucumber and Webrat / Selenium?

Tags: selenium, cucumber, webrat

I'm looking at a cucumber test suite that is somewhat brittle right now; many small steps, and no knowledge of the page itself.

I'd like to factor out the logic involved in the step definitions inside a series of Selenium PageObjects.  [As seen here.](http://www.trouble.net.au/blog/korny/2009/11/03/behaviour-driven-development-with-cucumber-and-selenium/)

However, because I'm using Webrat and not Selenium, everything has to go through the Webrat model.  So I cannot do

```
class MyPage < Selenium::WebPage

end
```

because that adds a direct dependency.

So I have to route everything through Webrat while still maintaining the Selenium Page object goodness.  No documentation on this that I can see: if someone has anything on Webrat + PageModel I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the answer is:

```
class MyPage < BasePage
  def visit
    @world.visit "/"
  end

end

class BasePage
  def initialize(world)
    @world = world
  end
end
```

And then in a step definition:

```
Given /I am awesome/ do
  page = MyPage.new(self)
  page.visit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

we just released something that sounds just like what you were after.
take a look at Gizmo - http://rubygems.org/gems/gizmo/
works with (webrat | capybara), (cucumber | rspec) etc..